# How to move from TFS visualstudio.com to GitHub in Visual Studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2017

I'm using VS2017 and have a few projects that I currently have wired up to TFS online (using Git) but I would like to switch it over to using GitHub repository. I've done some searching and all I can find is those asking how the opposite, moving from Git to TFS online.

At the moment I don't have a repository in GitHub for the couple projects. I didn't know if I should create the repository first or if changing source controls would it allow for setting up the repository in the process?

Anyone know an article I can look at or can tell me the steps I would need to take to move to GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to command-line to:

- [change the URL of your local cloned repository](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/) to a GitHub one (assuming you have created a new empty repo on GitHub)
- `git push --all`
- [clone back that new GitHub repo with VS2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/clone?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) to ensure everything is working

That would migrate the Git repo itself, but not work items.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with that. I don't really care about the history getting pushed over.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Repository in Github with the name you want.
2. In Visual Studio, click on Team Explorer > Home icon > Settings > Repository Settings.
3. Under Remotes, click Edit, and set the Fetch and Push paths to the new Github repository you created in (1) above (something like `https://github.com/youraccount/repositoryname.git`)

This sets the remote address to Github. Next, you need to push your local to the remote repository:

1. Click on the Manage Connections icon in Team Explorer
2. Under Local Git Repositories, right-click on your project name, and select Open Command Prompt
3. `git push --all`
4. It'll take a few seconds to minutes to upload
5. Refresh the Github page for that repository, and you'll see all files including the full history.

NOTE: If the command in (3) above doesn't work, you'll need to download Git from https://git-scm.com/downloads